# Can we provide multiple patterns for a single filter-chain in filterChainProxy

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have two patterns for which same filters are to be applied.

```
<security:filter-chain pattern="/home.do*" filters="a,b,c,d" />
<security:filter-chain pattern="/login.do*" filters="a,b,c,d" />
```

Along with the above two there are many other unique patterns and a generic pattern `/**/*.do*/**` as well.

Can I specify comma separated multiple patterns in the pattern attribute like below:

`<security:filter-chain pattern="/home.do*, /login.do*" filters="a,b,c,d" />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, but the implementation depends on Spring Security version you are using.

- In 3.0 you can use [`path-type`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-path-type) attribute:

  ```
  <security:filter-chain-map path-type="regex">
    <security:filter-chain pattern="^/(test|home)\.do$" filters="a,b,c,d" />
    <!-- other patterns -->
  <security:filter-chain-map path-type="regex">
  ```
- In 3.1 you can either use [`request-matcher`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-filter-chain-map-request-matcher) attribute (which deprecates `path-type`, just change path-type to request matcher in previous example), or you can use multiple `http` elements with [`request-matcher-ref`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http-request-matcher-ref) bean and do this:

  ```
  <http pattern="test.do,home.do" security="none" <!-- 'none' as example -->
      request-matcher-ref="requestMatcher" />

  <bean id="requestMatcher" class="com.example.CommaSeparatedRequestMatcher" />
  ```

  with your custom implementation of `CommaSeparatedRequestMatcher` (which splits URL created from request and triest to match any string), based on, for example, [`RegexRequestMatcher`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/RegexRequestMatcher.html).